# How to find my real latitude and longitude using JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I want to find my latitude and longitude using PHP.

I have tried multiple ways, but my solutions only show the service provider location and IP address. I want to find my real latitude and longitude.

I am using the below code but it's not working for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>

      <p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

      <button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

      <p id="demo"></p>

      <script>
        var x = document.getElementById("demo");

        function getLocation() {
          if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
          } else { 
          x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
          }
        }

        function showPosition(position) {
          x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
            "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
         }
      </script>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: PHP wont help, as that's a server side language, it can't find your real location by any means

Comment: Please remove the php tag as this has nothing to do with PHP

Comment: I don't see anything related to PHP here, hence removing the tag.  Also cleaned up formatting and grammar.

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.geolocation` will generally use the most precise data available to the browser.

If the client has a GPS (as phones tend to) then it will probably use that.

If it has Wi-fi, then it may be able to use nearby access points to determine the location.

If it has to fallback to GeoIP lookups, then it will only be a precise as the data held on the ISP.

You are currently suffering from using a client which is using the last of the above. You can't get more precise than that without changing the client.